# AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient Thread Configuration

Tags: aws-sdk

I am using following two libraries to publish spring boot metrics to aws cloud watch.

> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.0.1.RELEASE
>
> io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-cloudwatch:1.1.2

It uses AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient to asynchronously push metrics for every one minute and for that it creates fixedThreadPool of size 50 with the default configuration. I am looking for a simple way to override this thread count based on our need. Is there a property that controls this value? or what is the alternate way to configure the thread pool for AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CloudWatchExportAutoConfiguration class instantiates the AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient with default values. The bean factory method is annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingAmazonClient(AmazonCloudWatchAsync.class). So i was able customize the AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient by creating it in my configuration class with the executor service with less number of threads.

```
    @Bean
  public AmazonWebserviceClientFactoryBean<AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient> amazonCloudWatchAsync(
          AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider, RegionProvider regionProvider) {
    AmazonWebserviceClientFactoryBean<AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient> factoryBean =
            new AmazonWebserviceClientFactoryBean<>(AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient.class, credentialsProvider);
    factoryBean.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    factoryBean.setRegionProvider(regionProvider);
    return factoryBean;
  }
```